# How do i open a local terminal from a remote session in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When i open my workspace in VScode i go directly into my SSH work area, which is what i want. But i want to have a split terminal with access to both my SSH-work area and a terminal for my local computer, but i cant access the local one without making an explicitly new terminal from the dropdown window. And if i try to split the new local terminal i get the error "The terminal shell CWD "/Users/asd/work/" does not exist" as if its being looked for in my SSH work directory. Is there any way of specifying the default terminal to be on my local computer? If i do so in the terminal preferences in VScode i get the CWD-error on startup instead.

Comment: This looks like a VSCode bug (or bugs). You could open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should have been resolved with [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 1479](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1479)

> Both of you don't have `C:\Windows\System32` on your path, I don't understand why that is.
>
> But I will change this to not rely on the `PATH`.

Even if this was for Windows originally, opening a local shell, (Mac or Windows) should now be possible while having a remote session.

Wtih <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>(Command Palette), you have:

```
Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal (local)
```

---

Bonus, with VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021), there is now:

### [Remote layout persistence](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/3b98743d345c9edac402af17bdfe5471533dfe44/release-notes/v1_53.md#remote-layout-persistence)

Terminal layout is restored on remote terminal reconnection. In the video below, the terminal layout is restored when reloading VS Code and reconnecting to a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) remote instance.

[image: In a remote window, three split terminals are created and resized. On reload, the layout appears unchanged. -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_53/terminal-splits-persist.gif]